# Sign in as different user in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I use *SharePoint 2013* and I need to change my current user in my SharePoint site.

How can I change my current user?

How can I add sub menu (sign in as different user) to my menu ?

[image]

Comment: If user switching needs done regularly it's useful to use a non-IE browser to get the login prompt.

Comment: @James you could just disable the automatic login of IE (way on the bottom of the security screen) and always get a login prompt as well

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are several solutions to your problem as Microsoft has removed the *Sign in as different user* link.

1. Start your browser as a different user
2. Use the `_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true` page
3. Edit the `Welcome.aspx` to include the link again ([Sign in as Different User and SharePoint 2013](http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/sign-in-as-different-user-and-sharepoint-2013/))
4. Use JavaScript as a Bookmarklet ([SharePoint 2013 – Sign in as Another User](http://corypeters.net/2012/10/sharepoint-2013-sign-in-as-another-user/))

Official MSDN article about this problem: ["Sign in as Different User" menu option is missing in SharePoint Server 2013](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2752600). And remember: It's a feature, not a bug ;-)

Answer (score 1):

•Locate the file \15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\Welcome.ascx and open in a text editor.

•Add the following element before the existing element with the id of “ID_RequestAccess”:

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="ID_LoginAsDifferentUser"
 Text="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_loginasdifferentuser%>"
 Description="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_loginasdifferentuserdescription%>"
 MenuGroupId="100"
 Sequence="100"
 UseShortId="true"
/>
```

•Save the file and close.
•Open your SharePoint site.

You will get an option for Sign In as Different User below "About Me" option

Comment: ... which you couldn't do as any future update could destroy your modifications in original SharePoint files.

Answer (score 1):

I am aware of 5 workarounds:

– Running the browser as the user you want to log in. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2752600

– Accessing the following URL “http://siteurl/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true” by which you will be able to login as another user.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2752600

– Making a bookmarlet. Find how to do this [here](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/how-to-sign-in-as-a-different-user-in-sharepoint-2013/).

– Modify the “Welcome.ascx” control. You can find details about this [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mpriem/archive/2012/08/17/logging-in-as-a-different-user-in-sharepoint-2013-preview.aspx). This solution has two major inconvenients. Firstly, it is server scoped: the button will appear on every site collection of every web application. And secondly, the control can be overridden while applying a patch to SharePoint.

– Make a custom action. This gives the button back and is a clean way to do it.
[Step by step guide on my blog.](http://sprecipe.com/2015/11/28/pimp-my-sharepoint-episode-1-get-sign-in-as-different-user-back/)

Answer (score 1):

Unfotueanatly the Sign as a different user has been removed in SharePoint 2013

But you can

- Start Internet Explorer with Run as a different user option, by holding the Shift key when you right-click on a program icon.
- Provide the different user credential.
- Navigate to your SharePoint portal.

[image]

Also, there is a workaround to show Sign as a different user in SharePoint 2013 as SharePoint 2010 option by following the mentioned steps at [Sign in as a different user in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/03/sign-in-as-different-user-in-sharepoint-designer-2013/)

Comment: This is not useful for situations where you need to login as a SharePoint user rather than a local AD user.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround option is:

Start Internet Explorer by using the 'Run as different user option', and then go to the SharePoint site.

The 'Run as different user option' is visible if you hold the Shift key when you right-click a program icon.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below URL in your browser, which will prompt for login.

```
http://<yourservername>/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true
```

There is also a Chrome extension for this, refer this post:

[http://spshell.blogspot.com/2018/07/sharepoint-20132016-sign-in-as.html](http://%3Cyourservername%3E/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true)